# Cu3er SWF Font

Tags: flash

I have a free Cu3r Slider and I need to embed a font of mine. I tried sIFR but no succes.
Does anybody have all the settings we can make with the xml file for cu3er?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the way of embedding fonts into Flash:

1. Go to your library, right-click and choose "New Font ..."
2. Under the "Name" field type the name of the font, for example: "myFont".
3. Select font & style from the respective drop down menus.
4. Click "advanced > linkage" and check "Export for Actionscript" and "Export in first frame".
5. Click OK.
6. Open 'ActionScript panel' and in first frame register font by typing following AS code:

   ```
    function getFontNames():Array {
      return ["myFont"]; // list of export names of embedded fonts
    }
    stop();
   ```
7. Publish this swf for Flash Player 9 with Actionscript 3.